# getting an error when trying to open my heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, backend

[image: error from my heroku app]

here is the error i got when i used `heroku logs --tail`

everything worked fine, until i open the app and saw an application error text

my **server.js** code

```
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json");
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(port);
```

can i have any help with, please?

Comment: Show `package.json`

Comment: package.json has load of contents, if you can tell me what exactly i should check for, i will gladly do that

Comment: package.json has load of contents, if you can tell me what exactly i should check for, i will gladly do that

Comment: i have this concerning **JSON-SERVER** ```"devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.0"
  },```

Comment: I guess that `npm install` never runs. Maybe you have custom `procfile` or something like that